# CartoDB basemaps using CartoDB.js with createLayer

Tags: carto, carto-js, basemap

I've created a map on the CartoDB site and now wish to add some interactivity using CartoDB.js.

I'd like the interactive map to have the same basemap as on the CartoDB site, Nokia Hybrid Day.

The createVis method automatically loads the CartoDB basemap. But I need to use the createLayer method, which does not.

Could you please tell me how I can load the basemap I'm using on the CartoDB site for use with the createLayer method?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem.
I resolved it add a googlemap Layer to my map and not nokia map.

var map
 // create google maps map
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.44, 11.9),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID

```
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),  mapOptions);

    var sublayers;

    // Add other data layer to your map..........
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Could you please provide the code you use to add the CartoDB layers to a Google map object. The code I'm using `cartodb.createLayer(map, vizjson).addTo(map)` works with a Leaflet object, but is throwing an error when given a Google object.

Answer (score 0):

Check on [this website](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) on examples of layers to add to leaflet. Searching `HERE`  you'll find different basemaps that you can add to your blank leaflet map and after that, call `createLayer`.

Remember that in order to use HERE basemaps you need to register as a developer and get an `app-id` and `app_code`.

Additionally, you can also use the [leaflet-providers](https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers) plugin to instantiate those basemaps more easily.